# Google Maps API v3, Remove Marker icon or changing to "null"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, flask, google-maps-markers

I'm writing a Python Flask application in which I'm using Google Maps. I want to be able to add labels to a polyline that I've drawn which symbolizes a ship route.

The route is drawn using a set of coordinates and the polyline feature of the Maps API. I want to add time labels to the polyline and the easiest way seems to be to use Map Markers. However I don't want the large standard pins to show up, but would prefer a small icon/marker together with my text or even none at all. As far as I have gathered you can create "Circles" (which are modifiable) or "Markers" (which you only can change the icon of). I would prefer to go with "Circles", but those you apparently can't add text to..

How can I add text to my map and avoid the Google Maps Pins showing up?

Currently I have an list of objects that contains latitude, longitude and date + time. I'm iterating through it adding markers, but as I do I would like to keep out the marker icon or instead draw the circles if someone knows how to draw circles with added text?

```
for(i = 0; i < markerList.length; i++){
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markerList[i].lat, markerList[i].lng);
    var date = markerList[i].date;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        label: date,
        map: map,
        icon: "None" //Produces error: 404 (NOT FOUND)
    });
}
```

Being able to change the label size also is a very much appreciated function, but I have been unable to find any information about whether that is available. Being able to change the color of the text would also be nice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As no answers have been given yet and I've sort of found a solution to my problem I guess I will share for others out there with the same problem. At least until someone comes up with a better solution:

I ended up using a predefined symbol and scaling it down to 0 in size as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < markerList.length; i++){
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markerList[i].lat, markerList[i].lng);
    var date = markerList[i].date;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        label: date,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 0
        }
    });
}
```

Sadly I haven't found a way to mess with the label yet.

Answer (score 0):

try [markerWithlabel](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerwithlabel) and you can change the icon of the marker whit a svg or png plus the label too

like this [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/BV3XC/4)
`.`

Comment: Hello, can you please post a code snippet of how this user should use this resource? Generally, link-only answers are frowned upon by the SO community. For more information about this check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article.

Answer (score -1):

@Zeliax You can add `visible: false` to not have marker icon show on your google map. icon prop looks for a path that you want specify for your marker to look as. It is basically a url for your display image.